# Inline entity extra details

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I'm using the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) which is showing me too little information to know which entities are attached to a node. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

**How can I add other details to this form i:e the entity title so it human friendly and makes more sense at a glance?**